# Constructors that use <Class>... with reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I am trying to use a constructor for a class with reflection by doing:

```
MyClass.getConstructor(String.class, Array.newInstance(Car.class).getClass())
```

when the constructor for the class looks like this:

```
public MyClass(String var1, Car... var2)
```

But when the code I try to run that code (and create a new instance of the class) an IllegalArgumentException is thrown.

Comment: How would I initialize an array that would work with the "..." since there is no specific size

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Array.newInstance(Car.class).getClass()` isn't how you'd get the `Class` for type `Car[]`. The correct way to do that would just be

```
Car[].class
```

`Array.newInstance(Car.class)` asks Java for a 0-dimensional array, which is illegal.

If `Car` isn't hardcoded here, you'd need to use a 1-dimensional array of length 0, rather than a 0-dimensional array:

```
Array.newInstance(someClass, 0).getClass()
```

You could also construct the name of the array type and use `Class.forName`, but this is more readable and doesn't require a long else-if chain to get arrays of primitives right.

Comment: Thank you, also how would you do that with Class.forname("") because you cannot use ".class"

Comment: Then you would probably write `Array.newInstance(fooClass, 0)` to make a single-dimensional array of size 0.

Comment: @Nick Class names of arrays are explained [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName--).